# Android Custom Alert Dialog Display Error after changing the Build Version

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-build, android-version

I am developing a simple demo . Here in this demo, I am just creating one simple custom alert dialog . It works fine.

It shows me the perfect result when i build application in 1.6, but when i change the android version from 1.6 to 2.2, it shows the unexpected result. It doesn't show the background screen on which i display the custom alert dialog.

**Here is my xml file.**  **Custom Dialog Theme File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Theme.Dialog</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Here is My CustomConfirmOkDialog Class**

```
package com.utility.org;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomConfirmOkDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener
    {
        private Button okButton = null;
        private TextView infoText=null,confirmBody=null;
        private int errorMessage=0;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Activity activity;

        public CustomConfirmOkDialog(Activity context,int customdialogtheme,int errorMessage) 
        {
            super(context,customdialogtheme);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.confirm_ok);
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
            this.activity = context;
            initControls();
        }

        private void initControls()
        {
            okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            infoText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.infoText);
            confirmBody = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmBody);

            switch (this.errorMessage) 
            {

                case Utility.INVALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD:
                    try
                    {
                        infoText.setText(R.string.signIn);
                        confirmBody.setText(R.string.invalidUsernameAndPassword);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Calling this class from my main activity using the below code.

```
CustomConfirmOkDialog dialog = new CustomConfirmOkDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme, Utility.INVALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD);
dialog.show();
```

[image]
[image]

Here you can clearly notice that `1st image` shows the background . Its build in android 1.6 version while `2nd image` doesn't shows the background . It shows the entire black screen. Its build in android version 2.2 . I am very thankful if anyone can solve this issue.

Can anyone help me to solve this simple and silly issue ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you say change the version, do you mean the target version, min verion, or max version?  Or do you simply mean on a different device which has a  higher version?

Comment: i am talking about project build target version .

Comment: silly comment but i have faced the same issue so...are you testing the demo in emulator with sdk 2.2 cause the device or emulator cause sometimes the view doesn't shown perfectly when running higher version app to lower version emulator or device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It resolved my problem by changing the following code in Custom Dialog Theme xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. the problem is when I called constructor of Dialog class

Dialog(Context context, int themeId)

it will hide the background activity. The only solution that i found is don't call this constructor, instead only call

Dialog(Context context)

and set your style in the layout file.

So in your code, only write

super(context)

instead of

super(context, themeid);

Comment: It does not give the proper result what i want .

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a [known issue](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f578ec5a0bd9896e?pli=1).

> This only happens when you try **inheriting** from the framework  themes. 
>   Using `@android:style` directly will still treat them as non- 
>   fullscreen, which punches through the black background as expected.
>
> One workaround is to start with a nearly-blank theme (like Panel or 
>   Translucent) and then render what you need in your own layout (such as 
>   dialog edges, etc).

Thought, I still don't fully understand this solution myself yet.

And actually, I'm no longer sure they're talking about the exact same bug you've seen, since they're talking about it not working for an older version of the sdk (not a newer one like yours). See the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2480).